# Create a wordpress page by a json file

Tags: json, wordpress

I have a json file containing my restaurant menu

````
```
{"id":17135,"name":"Apperò","categories":[{"id":3343680,"name":"APERITIVO","color":"#F6B352","position":0,"type":"PRODUCT","products":[{"id":30510283,"name":"COPERTO","price":100,"position":0,"options":[]},
{"id":27271178,"name":"PETTOLE","price":250,"position":12,"image":{"thumbnail":"https://assets.tiller.systems/17135/products/27271178/thumbnail.png","small":"https://assets.tiller.systems/17135/products/27271178/small.png","medium":"https://assets.tiller.systems/17135/products/27271178/medium.png","large":"https://assets.tiller.systems/17135/products/27271178/large.png"},"options":[{"id":1218380,"category":"CONDIMENTI","products":[{"id":27271185,"name":"FORMAGGIO FUSO","price":100,"position":0},
{"id":27271189,"name":"CAPPERI","price":20,"position":1},
{"id":27271192,"name":"ACCIUGHE","price":50,"position":2},
{"id":27271200,"name":"CREMA DI RICOTTA FORTE","price":100,"position":3},
{"id":27271202,"name":"CREMA PICCANTE","price":100,"position":4},
{"id":27271203,"name":"VIN COTTO","price":50,"position":5},
{"id":27273149,"name":"RICOTTA","price":100,"position":6},
{"id":27273150,"name":"CACIORICOTTA STAGIONATO","price":100,"position":7},
{"id":27273171,"name":"CICORIA RIPASSATA","price":200,"position":8}]},
{"id":1218381,"category":"SALSE","products":[{"id":27264693,"name":"MAIONESE","price":50,"position":0},
{"id":27265590,"name":"KETCHUP","price":50,"position":1},
{"id":27266487,"name":"SENAPE","price":50,"position":2},
{"id":27268050,"name":"SALSA YOGURT","price":80,"position":3},
{"id":27270214,"name":"SALSA DI POMODORO","price":100,"position":4}]}]},
{"id":27271252,"name":"SPIEDINO DI CACIOCAVALLO SILANO","description":"Breaded and fried Caciocavallo skewer","price":250,"position":13,"image":{"thumbnail":"https://assets.tiller.systems/17135/products/27271252/thumbnail.png","small":"https://assets.tiller.systems/17135/products/27271252/small.png","medium":"https://assets.tiller.systems/17135/products/27271252/medium.png","large":"https://assets.tiller.systems/17135/products/27271252/large.png"},"options":[]}]},
{"id":3130810,"name":"POLPETTE","color":"#F68657","position":1,"type":"PRODUCT","products":[{"id":27270115,"name":"POLPETTE DI PANE PUGLIESI","description":"APULIAN BREAD MEATBALLS","price":300,"position":0,"image":{"thumbnail":"https://assets.tiller.systems/17135/products/27270115/thumbnail.png","small":"https://assets.tiller.systems/17135/products/27270115/small.png","medium":"https://assets.tiller.systems/17135/products/27270115/medium.png","large":"https://assets.tiller.systems/17135/products/27270115/large.png"},"options":[]}]}],"meals":[]} 
```
````

this file is updated by a script connected to my system .

I have a page in my wordpress site called "menu" and I want it to read this file and get the updated HTML from json.

How can I do that?

thank you

Comment: [Make a plugin](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/plugin-basics/).

Comment: You could use the WordPress REST API to import the data from the JSON file and create a new page from it. Does it help?

Comment: i have no idea about how to do that. i'll give it a try -